# Change color title bar

Tags: android, colors, titlebar

I want to change the color of the title bar. I tried this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ColorBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ColorBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/orange</item>
</style>
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong in my code shown above?

EDIT : it's the color of the text i want to change, not the background (it's running for the background)

Comment: i can't do it in the xml ? It's useless to do it in every activity :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for all devices, you will need the support library (appcompat_v7)

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@style/BaseTheme"></style>

<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/orange </item>
    <item name="background">@color/orange </item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Text</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Text</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/orange</item>
</style>
```

manifest :

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme"
```

Comment: there is a mistake, it's not the background i want to change, but the text in the title bar, i'm sorry

Comment: updated my answer :) ... background and text is both orange now, so ... yeah, change one of it :)

Comment: it says me it didn't find the att tilteTextStyle

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the parent to `parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid"` make a difference?

If not, let me know what happens if you move the

`<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ColorBar</item>` into the `AppBaseTheme` style

---

Try setting all of these:

```
    <item name="android:background">@color/something</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/something</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/something</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be problem with the android version. You should consider old ones and new ones. Try adding these both lines for different versions.

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/your_color</item>
<item name="background">@drawable/your_color</item>
```

Comment: there is a mistake, it's not the background i want to change, but the text in the title bar, i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way for settings the color of the actionbar-title by Java

```
getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#ffffff\">" + "TITLE" + "</font>"));
```

If you're using a support library, then you can use `getSupportActionBar();`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to all of this but I found it easier to go to Res > Value > colors.xml and from there you can change the "primary color."  This changed the title bar to the color I selected.