# I want to change title bar text color in material Components theme. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, material-components-android, material-components

I tried set title color but it is deprecated. I tried to change color by using

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
  </style>
```

as mentioned here: [ActionBar text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color) but the whole Titlebar color changes to white while doing it.
All I want to do is set my Black Title bar text color to white.
I also tried this solution here: [Change color title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801252/change-color-title-bar) but I am using the MaterialComponents theme and using AppCompactThemes makes my app crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add this to you base theme

```
 <item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item> //whatever color
```

Eg:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: Worked like charm! Simple and useful

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are not using a `Toolbar` the textcolor used in the ActionBar is based on the attribute `android:textColorPrimary`.
You can override it adding in your app theme the **`actionBarTheme`** attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Actionbar</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.Actionbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Surface" >
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

[image]

As alternative you can

Comment: Even though your answer may be correct and working, I prefer a simple solution as provided by @notTdar